# Apache2: reverse proxy subdomain to remote address with port and subfolder?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

On my Ubuntu server, I have installed Odoo at http://localhost:8069; Odoo is a Python application, and serves through a Python server.

When http://localhost:8069 is opened first, Odoo checks for currently logged in user; if there is none, it redirects to http://localhost:8069/web/login ; if there is a logged in user, it redirects to http://localhost:8069/web.

I would thus like to make http://localhost:8069/web available on a subdomain, say http://odoo.myserver.com - so the user does not have to be distracted by the port (the `:8069` part) and the subfolder (the `/web` part). In other words, the user should get the login page as http://odoo.myserver.com/login (instead of http://localhost:8069/web/login).

In my case, http://odoo.myserver.com is on the same computer as the one serving Odoo. So, I thought I'd try a reverse proxy in Apache2 for this. This is my subdomain configuration as a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName odoo.myserver.com
  ServerAdmin info@myserver.com
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/
  </Location>
  ProxyErrorOverride off
</VirtualHost>
```

When I have this active, and load http://odoo.myserver.com in my browser for the first time, I am redirected to http://odoo.myserver.com/web/login, and I get an Odoo styled 404 "Page not found" page.

If I try without a Location tag, and I map `/web` local to `/web` remote:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName odoo.myserver.com
  ServerAdmin info@myserver.com
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /web/ http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/
  ProxyPassReverse /web/ http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/
  ProxyErrorOverride off
</VirtualHost>
```

... then http://odoo.myserver.com simply gives me the default Apache page, and http://odoo.myserver.com/web/ does redirect to http://odoo.myserver.com/web/login (and something similar happens when I map as `ProxyPass(Reverse) / http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/`) - but this is not what I want.

---

EDIT: Closest I got to, was by following https://serverfault.com/questions/698995/apache-proxypass-redirect-subdomain-to-port-and-path :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName odoo.myserver.com
  ServerAdmin info@myserver.com
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8069/    
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8069/    
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web
  RewriteRule ^/$ /web/$1 [R,L]
  ProxyErrorOverride off
</VirtualHost>
```

... in which case, when I load http://odoo.myserver.com in my browser, I'm redirected to http://odoo.myserver.com/web/login, and I get a proper Odoo login page. Close enough, but still not there, because the `/web` part is still visible.

---

So, how would it be possible to proxy in such a way, that when:

- User loads http://odoo.myserver.com - gets http://127.0.0.1:8069/web
- User loads http://odoo.myserver.com/login - gets http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/login

...?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName odoo.myserver.com
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  <Location /login>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/login
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8069/web/login
  </Location>
  <Location />
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8069/web
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8069/web
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Try this config