# Odoo how to keep the port number in the address bar Nginx

Tags: nginx, odoo, reverse-proxy

my home have static IP but have with port 80,443 Block, I use port fowarding in router 8069 > odoo server port 443 > rever proxy 8069
SSL is ok, I'm using certbot over DNS, everytime I need to access odoo is,

hit https://erp.example.com:8069

> Return [ERROR 503] https://erp.example.com/web

which nginx remove the port automatically,

hit https://erp.example.com:8069/web/login

> Return [Success] https://erp.example.com:8069/web/login

### when put full address port_number/ it does the work

is there any solution let nginx not to redirect what I input at address bar? I need keep the custom port

this isn't what I need, Nginx trying redirect to what I entered 8069 to 443 port, which 443 port has block by ISP

Comment: add nginx configuration you are using

Comment: @sdaau I switched to apache, it's close to our gold 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118186/apache2-reverse-proxy-subdomain-to-remote-address-with-port-and-subfolder

Comment: Edit on 2022-07-30
When I **switch Nginx to Apache**, in apache does the work closely

 hit https://erp.example.com:8069
 

> Return http://erp.example.com:8069/web

 
 

add https again https://erp.example.com:8069/web

            

> Return http://erp.example.com/web/login
> 
add https again https://erp.example.com:8069/web/login
> 
> 
> Return [Success]

our goal is

      

hit https://erp.example.com:8069
> 
> 
> Return https://erp.example.com:8069/web/login

        but Failed